# Javascript Form Validation Issue

Tags: javascript, html, email

I use a simple javascript form validation function on my ecard site.

This is the function:
http://jimpix.co.uk/dist/js/ecard.js

This is a sample page which calls the .js file:
http://jimpix.co.uk/ecards/4244-new-year.html

This is the relevant bit of the function I have a problem with:

```
// otherwise split the string using commas
var cCheck = myString.indexOf(",");
if (cCheck === -1) {
    var cMsg = 'Please remember to split email addresses with a comma';
}
var fback = "";
for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    emailCheck = validateEmail(trim(mySplitResult[i]));
    if (false === emailCheck) {
        fback = fback + "\n" + mySplitResult[i];
    }
}
if (!!fback) {
    fback = 'Please correct the following email addresses:\n ' + fback;
    if (!!cMsg && i === 1) {
        fback = fback + '\n\n' + cMsg;
    }
    alert(fback);
    theForm.whotoemail.focus();
    return false;
}
```

When users enter recipient email addresses, they need to split them with commas.

The form only accepts 10 email addresses, but users often leave a comma at the end of the last email address.

When they do that, and click to preview or send the ecard, they get a message saying:

Please correct the following email addresses:

However, there is no email address to correct - it's just that the last character in the form value is a comma.

I just wondered if anyone might please be able to advise how I can get the javascript to NOT split if the last character in the "whotoemail" field is a comma.

Or if there is a tidier solution?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: Why don't you just remove the last character if it's a comma before splitting?

Comment: Check the length of your mySplitResult array during execution.  It likely has one last index that is empty.  You are failing to validate that as a valdia address.  Check for that case and remove it from the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go for an easy fix:

```
for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    if(mySplitResult[i] == "")
        continue; // skip empty strings
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful suggestion. I have implemented that.